# Do you all talk about MMA fights here? Or is...it illegal?

Tags: discussion

So yeah that's just my question. I don't want to ask about MMA fights and stuff and then get banned into non existence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can ask about MMA. [Help](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) describes what kinds of questions are allowed. In particular,

> your question should have a clear answer. It should not prompt extended debate or invite opinion.

[Help also describes the kinds of questions that will be closed](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Overly subjective, chatty, or open-ended questions about MMA will still be closed.

Comment: Yep, good answer - just remember it is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Ah alright, cool enough. Thank you.